# Методология структурирования каталогов и файлов на сайте?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, code-style, style-guide

Как структурировать сайт, то есть папки и файлы. Существуют ли шаблоны какие то, либо методологии. И как этот процесс называется?

Comment: Можно подсмотреть в любом веб-фреймворке, например

Comment: Ага, то есть через fw, хорошо. А методологии?

Comment: Структура папок сильно зависит от используемого языка. Т.е. для nodejs будет популярна одна схема, для asp.net - другая, для php - третья.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите паттернов, то их есть у меня)

Подход при котором одна входная точка на все приложение (кроме статики), называется front controller. Так работают все фреймворки:

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html

Подход при котором на каждый тип страниц своя входная точка, называется page controller. В современном мире такое может быть либо как легаси, либо самописная система на php:

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html

А вообще все сильно зависит от того что вы имеете ввиду. Если речь про загружаемые файлы (статику), то это одна история, если про исходный код то другая.

Как правило сайты не пишут на голом языке, всегда есть фреймворк/cms, а они задают структуру.

Важно понимать что файлы сайта и то что вы видите в адресной строке, это не одно и тоже.

Comment: Так будет лучше?

Comment: Спасибо, кое что для себя уяснил!

Answer (score 0):

Нет, шаблонов или методологий повсеместных нет. Как уже написали в комментарии, обычно часто языки/фреймфорки/веб-сервера/пакеты налагают свои правила но они далеки от стандарта.

Собственно и у [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) по этому поводу ничего не сказано.

Тем не менее есть негласные правила дошедшие до нас со времён статичных сайтов, вот некоторые из них:

`/js` `/scripts` - скрипты

`/css` `/styles` - стили

`/img` `/images` - изображения

Прошу в комментариях дополнить, какие ещё стандартные директории есть.

Comment: /fonts - шрифты, /files - файлы